# Port is reachable on telnet locally, but browser shows connection reset

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, browser, vmware, web

I am running a web application server locally in an Ubuntu guest VM on a Windows host.

I could not connect to the service in any web browser. Chrome reported ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED. The result is the same using 127.0.0.1 and localhsot. Looking at chrome://net-internals/#proxy the browser is using direct connection, not through proxies.

I can telnet to the port, suggesting the port is open.
I tried changing the port of the service, the new port is again reachable using telnet but unreachable using web browser.
Another similar service running on Tomcat is reachable in browser, suggesting browser is good.
The other service talks to the service in problem via a second port, the program ran without errors.

The web application server is Jetty, run directly from JARs using a wrapper of Java runtime. The software is a package solution so I cannot see Jetty logs.

Changes I made between used-to-work and not-working:
I installed and reinstalled and uninstalled and reinstalled several times the following apt packages or software on the Ubuntu guest:
VMWare Tools
open-vm-tools
open-vm-tools-lts-trusty
open-vm-tools-lts-trusty-desktop
open-vm-tools-lts-trusty-dkms (don't know what it does though),
after which integration between host and VM started to work.

The network adapter connection status changed on the host:
The host is a Dell laptop. I was trying to get wireless connection to be connected at the same time wired connection is connected. I was not successful. This morning wireless miraculously connected alongside wired connection. After I ran into the problem in the VM, I tried changing the connection sequence putting wired before wireless. It did not help. VM network is set to use NAT, sharing the host's IP address.

Any idea how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: One clue: the other service that works is on HTTP. This one is on HTTPS. The other service is configured to use a truststore file to talk to the service unreachable in browser. The unreachable HTTPS service is using a keystore and a truststore, it used to be the browser warns you about the SSL certificate issuer. Now it just doesn't even warn you? I did upgrade Chrome and Firefox between working and not working.

Comment: But then it's contradictory again. On the host browser, where such SSL issues are reported, and where the port is open per telnet (using the VM's IP address), Firefox still reports "Firefox can't establish a connection to the server".

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be an issue with the web browser. It seems after updating to the latest versions, Firefox and Chrome stopped prompting for security exceptions, but instead refuses to display at all. Reverting to an old version of Firefox fixed the issue.

Still looking on how to control that new behavior though.